# Integrate convergent or divergent?

Tags: integration

We have the following integral:

From 1 to Infinity: |sin(x)| / x dx

Is this integral convergent or divergent(sin(X) is positive only)

Comment: Hint: Bound each integral $\int_{n\pi}^{{(n+1)}\pi}|\sin x|/x\,dx$ below using a "triangular function".

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}|\sin(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^\pi\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\left[\vphantom{\int}-\cos(x)\right]_0^\pi\\
&=2
\end{align}
$$
Then consider that on $[n\pi,(n+1)\pi]$ we have
$$
\frac1x\ge\frac1{(n+1)\pi}
$$